# NSIS execute command line command using IfSIlent jump

Tags: installation, nsis, uninstallation, silent, silent-installer

I am trying to make my installer uninstall silently by running the setup a second time. Using SetSilent under the function un.onInit works for when you manually click the executable, but doesn't work when you run it silently through the command line. I believe it is do to multiple threads running (the installer running alongside the uninstaller executable) so to correct this I wanted to use the IfSilent jump and run a command line command if the installer is running silently. Here is what I have.

`IfSilent 0 +2`

`Exec '"$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe" /S'`

I have nested this within the main section with the included files. I have checked and it doesn't seem like the above command is being executed. Is the above `exec` command being used correctly?

UPDATE: I have added some of the code from the installer I'm trying to create.  What I want to do is I want to check the system to see if the application exists somewhere on the target machine.  If it does I want to uninstall the previous version.

```
#Installer Functions
Function .onInit

    ReadRegStr $R0 HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\$(^Name)" "UninstallString"
    StrCmp $R0 "" done

    ;Run the uninstaller
    ClearErrors
    ExecWait '"$R0" /S _?=$INSTDIR'
    IfErrors no_remove_uninstaller done
    no_remove_uninstaller:
    done:
        InitPluginsDir
FunctionEnd
```

Now here is my problem.  This works if I'm installing this normally.  However when I try to install this silently, the uninstaller does not execute.

Please note, I'm using $R0 because I want to handle the scenario where the user may select a different directory then the install directory.  I have also tried using INSTDIR but it's still not working

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are trying to do, please clarify.

Comment: I'm trying to uninstall the previous version of my app before I perform my installation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the uninstaller with a special parameter:

```
ExecWait '"$INSTDIR\uninstaller.exe" /S _?=$INSTDIR'
Delete "$INSTDIR\uninstaller.exe"
```